# Generate a series of dates, based on rules

Tags: excel

I would like to generate a series of dates based on my business rules, preferably using Excel or other Office products.

Example of business rules:

- Include all Tuesdays, Thursdays, and Fridays.
- Exclude the last day of
  every month.

This would produce:

```
27 Jun 2017
29 Jun 2017
04 Jul 2017 
06 Jul 2017
07 Jul 2017
```

I don't need a complete solution, if you can recommend which features to use and a general approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We would need more information, such as if the generated dates are random, all in the next 12 months (or 12 years), every week for the next four months, etc. Look at the [NETWORKDAYS](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/networkdays.php) function.

Comment: Let's assume we're filtering all the valid dates starting from today, for the next year. Answerers below have made this assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force method.

In A1 put the starting date.

Then in A2 use the array formula:

```
=MIN( IF((A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7"))<>EOMONTH(A1,0))*((WEEKDAY(A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=3)+(WEEKDAY(A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=5)+(WEEKDAY(A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=6)),A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7"))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or you can use this non CSE formula in A2 that does not need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))/(((WEEKDAY(a1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=3)+(WEEKDAY(a1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=5)+(WEEKDAY(a1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7")))=6))*(A1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:7"))<>EOMONTH(A1,0))),1)
```

Format A2 as desired.  Then copy down

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed that my date formatting reverted to "general" when I entered this, so as you mentioned it is necessary apply formatting to the newly generated cells.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

In cell A1, put the starting date (June 27, 2017 using your example)

In cell A2 and copied down, use this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(((WEEKDAY(A1+{7,6,5,4,3,2,1})=3)+(WEEKDAY(A1+{7,6,5,4,3,2,1})=5)+(WEEKDAY(A1+{7,6,5,4,3,2,1})=6))*(A1+{7,6,5,4,3,2,1}<>EOMONTH(A1,0))),A1+{7,6,5,4,3,2,1})
```